# Socket.io Not Upgrading in Native UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, node.js, socket.io, nsurlconnection

I've been at this for days withot luck. Any help is much appreciate

I realize this is something of a cross between a Node question and an iOS question -- apologies in advance. I'm trying to build a simple collaborative whiteboard using HTML5/JS which is displayed in a native iOS app using a UIWebView (not phonegap). The JS uses socket.io to connect to a Node.js server for real-time doodling.

The socket works great when the HTML/JS is run in a browser, including mobile safari. However, when the same code is run natively in the webView, it will connect to the server but will not complete the upgrade process, so the server downgrades the connection to polling.

The behavior is the same regarldess of whether NGINX proxies are being used (they're properly forwarded) and regardless of whether it's using ws: or wss:.

This is problem, because the real-time drawing creates too many transmissions requests, causing slow app, bad drawings, and the socket.io library to throw an error:

> "Error: after called too many times" in socket.io/socket.io.js Line
>   4720.

I have a subclass of NSURLProtocol to catch and view the socket.io requests. I could modify the request to make the server happy, but I don't know what to modify. The output, displays request.URL.absoluteString, request.allHTTPHeaderFields, and request.HTTPBody, as well as responses.

```
 z2015-02-13 03:36:07.424 DrawApp[2286:553479] ||---------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-13 03:36:07.426 DrawApp[2286:553479] Request URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js
2015-02-13 03:36:07.432 DrawApp[2286:553479] RequestHead: {
    Accept = "*/*";
    Referer = "http://192.168.0.16:8081/mobilechat/16074204562:troy";
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466";
}
2015-02-13 03:36:07.434 DrawApp[2286:553479] RequestBody: (null)
2015-02-13 03:36:07.446 DrawApp[2286:553479] ---------------------------------------------------------------||
2015-02-13 03:36:07.455 DrawApp[2286:553456] ||---------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-13 03:36:07.455 DrawApp[2286:553456] Request URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js
2015-02-13 03:36:07.456 DrawApp[2286:553456] RequestHead: {
    Accept = "*/*";
    Referer = "http://192.168.0.16:8081/mobilechat/16074204562:tom";
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466";
}
2015-02-13 03:36:07.456 DrawApp[2286:553456] RequestBody: (null)
2015-02-13 03:36:07.457 DrawApp[2286:553456] ---------------------------------------------------------------||
2015-02-13 03:36:07.457 DrawApp[2286:553456] ||---------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-13 03:36:07.458 DrawApp[2286:553456] Request URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js
2015-02-13 03:36:07.458 DrawApp[2286:553456] RequestHead: {
    Accept = "*/*";
    Referer = "http://192.168.0.16:8081/mobilechat/16074204562:troy";
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466";
}
2015-02-13 03:36:07.459 DrawApp[2286:553456] RequestBody: (null)
2015-02-13 03:36:07.459 DrawApp[2286:553456] ---------------------------------------------------------------||
2015-02-13 03:36:07.467 DrawApp[2286:553456] ||---------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-13 03:36:07.468 DrawApp[2286:553456] Request URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js
2015-02-13 03:36:07.468 DrawApp[2286:553456] RequestHead: {
    Accept = "*/*";
    Referer = "http://192.168.0.16:8081/mobilechat/16074204562:tom";
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466";
}
2015-02-13 03:36:07.469 DrawApp[2286:553456] RequestBody: (null)
2015-02-13 03:36:07.469 DrawApp[2286:553456] ---------------------------------------------------------------||
2015-02-13 03:36:07.482 DrawApp[2286:553483] Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1463c1f0> { URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/javascript";
    Date = "Fri, 13 Feb 2015 08:36:20 GMT";
    Etag = "1.3.3";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }
2015-02-13 03:36:07.674 DrawApp[2286:553479] ||---------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-13 03:36:07.675 DrawApp[2286:553479] Request URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423816567670-0
2015-02-13 03:36:07.676 DrawApp[2286:553479] RequestHead: {
    Referer = "http://192.168.0.16:8081/mobilechat/16074204562:troy";
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466";
}
2015-02-13 03:36:07.677 DrawApp[2286:553479] RequestBody: (null)
2015-02-13 03:36:07.679 DrawApp[2286:553479] ---------------------------------------------------------------||
2015-02-13 03:36:07.722 DrawApp[2286:553483] Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1461c0c0> { URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423816567670-0 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 101;
    "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
    Date = "Fri, 13 Feb 2015 08:36:20 GMT";
    "Set-Cookie" = "io=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA";
} }
2015-02-13 03:36:08.150 DrawApp[2286:553479] ||---------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-13 03:36:08.151 DrawApp[2286:553479] Request URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423816568146-1&sid=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA
2015-02-13 03:36:08.153 DrawApp[2286:553479] RequestHead: {
    Referer = "http://192.168.0.16:8081/mobilechat/16074204562:troy";
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466";
}
2015-02-13 03:36:08.155 DrawApp[2286:553479] RequestBody: (null)
2015-02-13 03:36:08.156 DrawApp[2286:553479] ---------------------------------------------------------------||
2015-02-13 03:36:08.199 DrawApp[2286:553483] Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x146104b0> { URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423816568146-1&sid=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 5;
    "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
    Date = "Fri, 13 Feb 2015 08:36:21 GMT";
    "Set-Cookie" = "io=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA";
} }
2015-02-13 03:36:08.494 DrawApp[2286:553479] ||---------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-13 03:36:08.495 DrawApp[2286:553479] Request URL: http://192.168.0.16:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423816568491-2&sid=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA
2015-02-13 03:36:08.496 DrawApp[2286:553479] RequestHead: {
    Referer = "http://192.168.0.16:8081/mobilechat/16074204562:troy";
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466";
}
2015-02-13 03:36:08.497 DrawApp[2286:553479] RequestBody: (null)
2015-02-13 03:36:08.498 DrawApp[2286:553479] ---------------------------------------------------------------||
```

The corresponding DEBUG Log in Node shows:

```
  engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +0ms
  engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423
816567670-0" +3ms
  engine handshaking client "T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA" +5ms
  engine:socket sending packet "open" ({"sid":"T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA","upgrades":
["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}) +3ms
  engine:polling setting request +4ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +2ms
  engine:polling writing "      ?0{"sid":"T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA","upgrades":["web
socket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}" +5ms
  engine:socket executing batch send callback +4ms
-----------------
Log From io.use(function(socket, next){}):
 { host: '192.168.0.16:8081',
  referer: 'http://192.168.0.16:8081/mobilechat/12024804552:troy',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  accept: '*/*',
  cookie: '_ga=GA1.1.2050046519.1423642387; _gat=1; connect.sid=s%3AjmTKnmpC10Vv
PPRYBQBEabJtrrdQtqrZ.nz%2FlScJuQwV3JjSk9IWhVkTbYpxb8xkxqs%2FJXgjuJJw',
  'accept-language': 'en-us',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.
1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466' }
-----------------
  engine:socket sending packet "message" (0) +21ms
  engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +444ms
  engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423
816568146-1&sid=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA" +2ms
  engine setting new request for existing client +4ms
  engine:polling setting request +2ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +2ms
  engine:polling writing " ☻?40" +2ms
  engine:socket executing batch send callback +3ms
  engine upgrading existing transport +39ms
  engine:socket might upgrade socket transport from "polling" to "websocket" +2m
s
-----------------
Logged From: server.addListener('upgrade', function(req, socket, head){}):
HEADER: { upgrade: 'websocket',
  connection: 'Upgrade',
  host: '192.168.0.16:8081',
  origin: 'http://192.168.0.16:8081',
  cookie: 'io=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA; _ga=GA1.1.2050046519.1423642387; _gat=1; con
nect.sid=s%3AjmTKnmpC10VvPPRYBQBEabJtrrdQtqrZ.nz%2FlScJuQwV3JjSk9IWhVkTbYpxb8xkx
qs%2FJXgjuJJw',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'sec-websocket-key': 'My1vb8kKk82RVibaOvpNEw==',
  'sec-websocket-version': '13',
  'sec-websocket-extensions': 'x-webkit-deflate-frame',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.
1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B466' }
URL: /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA
-----------------
  engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +274ms
  engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423
816568491-2&sid=T_ZsAMyrO8RGOe46AAAA" +1ms
  engine setting new request for existing client +4ms
  engine:polling setting request +2ms
  engine:socket client did not complete upgrade - closing transport +10s
Disconnect type is: XHR
```

Note at the end we get:

> client did not complete upgrade - closing transport.

And on disconnect, we verify that:

> Disconnect type is: XHR

Sorry for the log dump, but I'm not really sure what's relevant to those who understand this better than I do.

Cheers